# how to wrap a text child inside a flex column and keep the width of the column fix

Tags: html, css, flexbox, word-wrap

I create a flex row which have 2 column each one have `flex:1` which mean the columns will divide the row by 2 parts have equal width

**HTML :**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="columnLeft">
  <p>columnLeft</p>
</div>
<div class="columnRight">
  <p>columnRight</p>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
 }
.columnLeft {
  flex:1;
  background-color: coral;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.columnRight {
  flex:1;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

**the result:**
[image: result]

**The problem:**
the problem is when I add  **text** in `columnLeft` that have width superior that the `columnLeft` the width of the column follow the width of it's child and broke the role of `flex:1 flex:1`.

[image: here result after change]

How to fix the width of a column in a row and wrap things inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `word-break: break-all` for the `<p>` if it has a long title like you showed in the question

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
 }
.columnLeft {
  flex:1;
  background-color: coral;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.columnRight {
  flex:1;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

p {word-break: break-all;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="columnLeft">
  <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
</div>
<div class="columnRight">
  <p>columnRight</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks , but what if a have a div with a fix width not a text ?

Comment: what do you mean by fixed width, can you explain briefly? or add it to your question perhaps

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .row {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
  }
 .columnLeft {
  flex:1;
  background-color: coral;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
 .columnRight {
   flex:1;
   background-color: green;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="row">
  <div class="columnLeft">
   <p>columnLeft columnLeft columnLeft columnLeft columnLeft columnLeft 
      columnLeft columnLeft columnLeft columnLeft columnLeft columnLeft 
      columnLeft columnLeft columnLeft columnLeft columnLeft 
      columnLeft</p>
  </div>
  <div class="columnRight">
   <p> columnRight </p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).